# Where statement in LINQ from sql

Tags: linq

I am trying to convert a SQL statement to LINQ.

I have this as SQL:

```
SELECT mutDetail.*
FROM hallo.Mutatie as mut
JOIN hallo.MutatieDetail AS mutDetail ON mut.MutatieID =  mutDetail.fkMutatieID
JOIN tblMedewerker AS med ON med.MedewerkerID = mut.fkMedewerkerID
JOIN tblKlant AS klant ON klant.KlantID = med.fkKlantID
WHERE mutDetail.BronCode = 'Personeelsnummer' 
  AND klant.KlantNummer = '78555522'
```

And this is my LINQ statement:

```
public IQueryable<Mutatie> GetMutatiesInstroom()
{
    var mutaties = (from m in context.Mutatie
                    join mutDetail in context.MutatieDetail on m.MutatieID equals mutDetail.fkMutatieID
                    join med in context.tblMedewerker on m.fkMedewerkerID equals med.MedewerkerID
                    join klant in context.tblKlant on med.fkKlantID equals klant.KlantID                                                        
                    select m);

    return mutaties;
}
```

But how to write the where statement in LINQ?

Thank you

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Your edit invalidates the answers posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was, but isn't it simple? Before `select m`:

`where m.BronCode == "Personeelsnummer" && klant.KlantNummer == "8700"`

Complete query as requested:

```
var mutaties = from m in context.Mutatie
               join mutDetail in context.MutatieDetail on m.MutatieID equals mutDetail.fkMutatieID
               join med in context.tblMedewerker on m.fkMedewerkerID equals med.MedewerkerID
               join klant in context.tblKlant on med.fkKlantID equals klant.KlantID        
               where m.BronCode == "Personeelsnummer" && klant.KlantNummer == "8700"                                             
               select m;
```

Comment: HI Tim, but can you give the complete LINQ statement. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It should go here:

```
public IQueryable<Mutatie> GetMutatiesInstroom()
{
    var mutaties = (from m in context.Mutatie
                    join mutDetail in context.MutatieDetail on m.MutatieID equals mutDetail.fkMutatieID
                    join med in context.tblMedewerker on m.fkMedewerkerID equals med.MedewerkerID
                    join klant in context.tblKlant on med.fkKlantID equals klant.KlantID   
                    where (mutDetail.BronCode == "Personeelsnummer" && 
                           klant.KlantNummer == "8700")                                
                    select m);

    return mutaties;
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0019 Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'

Comment: "mutDetail.BronCode" OR "klant.KlantNummer" is anyone boolean field?

Comment: oh, you forgot the ==. ok. Thank you

Comment: Updated the query. :)

Comment: declare a variable like *string klantNummer;* and use this in the query 
*klant.KlantNummer == klantNummer* make sure to assign the value  before the linq query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from microsofts documentation on how to add a filter in Linq statement.

```
var queryLondonCustomers = from cust in customers
                       where cust.City == "London"
                       select cust;
```

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations

right under section Filtering